# OSX crash log: How can I find what line in my app caused this crash?

Tags: macos, crash, crash-reports

Someone else got this error, how do I find out the source of this crash?

Not sure what file libdyld.dylib is nor am sure how to understand the exception type and code.

```
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F1077)

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.themolehill.tickmac         0x000000010bf9bb6b 0x10bf98000 + 15211
1   com.themolehill.tickmac         0x000000010bf996b6 0x10bf98000 + 5814
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87d77718 -[NSViewController view] + 41
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87f2b4c2 -[NSPopover showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge:] + 172
4   com.themolehill.tickmac         0x000000010bfa8371 0x10bf98000 + 66417
5   com.themolehill.tickmac         0x000000010bfabb55 0x10bf98000 + 80725
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87e8ba58 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 11296
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87f8711b -[NSStatusBarWindow sendEvent:] + 247
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87e2a5d4 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2021
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87c7a9f9 -[NSApplication run] + 646
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87c65783 NSApplicationMain + 940
11  com.themolehill.tickmac         0x000000010bfa7403 0x10bf98000 + 62467
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff86caa5fd start + 1
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: ksl, upvote it and hopefully someone will be able to answer it